# Unable to downvote question after marking it as Unsalvageable in Triage Review

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, triage

I was reviewing Triage Review Queue. There I marked one question as Unsalvageable. After that screen moved to next question for review. I expected it to wait on same question to downvote or add comment on question as I'm flagging it as Unsalvageable.
Take another scenario, when there is consensus of question "Looks Ok" then it will allow or suggest us to upvote question.

Comment: unable to? Didn't get an automatic chance to, more like. Reading your title i thought you used History to find a link to the question and downvote it but were somehow prevented to.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature in [triage](/questions/tagged/triage) review queue to downvote the questions.

The scenario is as following:

1. If 2 user has vote a question as **Looks Good** then it will ask to upvote to next user.
2. If more than 2 users vote as **Unsalvageable** then it will reach to consider it again and to improve.
3. If more than 2 users flag as close then it will consider to close the question.

If you want to *downvote* or *leave a comment* on any question then first open that question in new tab. Leave your comment or downvote and move to next.

I think this will be best way and in current scenario.